# How do I implement a form submission if the form is in my base template file?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a base template file that holds the form for the users to subscribe to the email newsletter. All of my templates inherit from the base template file, as I'd like to display this form on every web page.

**I don't know how do I make the form submit the data the user inputs into the database.** So far, I dealt with views and each view was specific to a URL, so it's not really obvious to me how do I do this for all URLs, since the base template is present on all URLs.

`base.html` (the base template file):

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
   <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="{% url 'employers:list_joblistings' %}"> Homepage </a>
   <a href="{% url 'employers:submit_job_listing' %}"> Post a job </a>
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   <p> Subscribe to new jobs: </p>
   <form method="post">
       <p> Email: <input type="email" name="email" /> </p>
       <p> First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /> </p>
       <p> Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /> </p>
       <input type="submit" value= "Submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also made a form in my `forms.py` file which constructs the form from my email subscriber model, but I don't use it anywhere so far:

```
EmailSubscriberForm = modelform_factory(EmailSubscriber, fields=["email", "first_name", "last_name"])
```

**How do I achieve what I want?**

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a `ModelForm`, that will link a form to a model when calling `save()` method. (this will add a lot of security too)

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import EmailSubscriber

# Create the form class.
class EmailSubscriberForm(ModelForm):
    # if email is an EmailField, `is_valid` method will check if it's an email
    class Meta:
        model = EmailSubscriber
        fields = ["email", "first_name", "last_name"]
```

Then in the view you can create and pass as a context or get the response and save to the database

```py
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EmailSubscriberForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email_subscriber = form.save()
    # generally call `return HttpResponseRedirect` here
else:
    form = EmailSubscriberForm()
    # generally call `return render(request, 'page.html', {'form': form})
```

and you just call this in your template :

```py
<form method="post">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I've got two questions: 1) How do I link the view to the form (since the form is omnipresent on my website and has no specific URL)? 2) Why shouldn't I use `modelform_factory`? Why inherit from `ModelForm` instead?

Comment: Maybe you can create a middleware that will be in charge of checking if you have this form submited and treat the data, before returning to the current page